# How to use "ça" and "me'' in phrases like "ça m'a rendue"?

Tags: pronoms

I was just going through my textbook when I came across a phrase and I did a lot of research into which grammatical rules it used but I still don't understand.

> Ça m'a rendue.

I thought at first that the "m'a rendue" was perfect tense but then why is there a "me" being involved. Or is this just one of those phrases like "J'ai de la chance".

According to google translate, this phrase means "it made me".

Comment: *Ça m'a rendue* is a part of a sentence that can't have stood on its own. Can you please give more context, at least the complete sentence or enough to give you a sensible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Google translate is right;

Ça m'a rendue folle de colère.
*It made me raving mad.*

"Me" is just the translation of the object "me".

The tense is the "passé composé" :
ai rendu(e)(s)(es), as rendu(e)(s)(es), a rendu(e)(s)(es), avons rendu(e)(s)(es), etc.